# How do I list tabs on a standalone page?

Tags: facebook, graph, tabs

I've created a page on Facebook without creating an account. This means that a default account is created with the page_id the same as the account_id.

When I try and perform a graph call to the tabs on the page:

```
/<page_id>/tabs?auth_token=<auth token>
```

I get an empty "data" representation:

```
{
  "data": [

  ]
}
```

Even though there are application tabs installed.

Add the tab_id makes no difference, I get the same response.

I'm guessing the page is getting confused as the account but I cannot find any way to distinguish the difference between the account and the page.

Does anyone know if it is possible to retrieve the page information another way?

Comment: Are you using the Page access token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double-check that the access token you're using is the [Page Access Token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/pages/) - this is the most likely reason this will fail to return an answer

Comment: Yeah it seems we have 2 different applications managing our pages on Facebook. We install with one but somewhat use another for other functions.

Comment: Yeah is seems we are using 2 different accounts to manage the application we have deployed. Now I need to re-engineer this part to try and consolidate it.